# OnClick event in ListView row with two Buttons

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-listview, listadapter

Situation:

- I have a `ListView` with my own `ListAdapter`.
- In *every* row I have two `Buttons`.

I'm trying to implement the `onClick` methods for the two `Buttons`, but I don't find the right solution. This is the `getView` method from my `ListAdapter` with my two `Buttons`:

```
    public View getView(final int groupPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modul_item, null);
         }

         TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modul_title);
         tv.setText(modul_overviewActivity.getvalue().get(groupPosition));

         Button Button_1 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button Button_2 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    return convertView;
}
```

- In my `OnCLickListeners` I want to change parameters of the `Objects` which are displayed in the `ListView`.
- The Name of the `Objects` is displayed, but they have a few more parameters (variables), which I want to edit in another `Activity`.
- This `Activity` should open if I click one of the `Buttons`.

Comment: is that c#? May you please specify the language somehow (either in the text or in the tags). Thanks!

Comment: it's about android, so it's java!

Comment: well it is not a statement, you can program in Android also with C# or php.

Comment: ok sorry, i didn't know that!

Comment: If you want help you should add more details: what have you tried until know, what do you want to do in those `OnClickListener`, what errors have you encountered etc

Comment: ok thanks, i just added some informations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly what you want to do in your button listeners but check this code:

```
public View getView(final int groupPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modul_item, null);
         }

         TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modul_title);
         tv.setText(modul_overviewActivity.getvalue().get(groupPosition));

         Button Button_1 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                    //this is how you start a new Activity(i guess you want this for editing the details)
            Intent i = new Intent(List4.this, DetailsAct.class);            
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });
         Button Button_2 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    return convertView;
}
```

This is just for starting a new activity, the intent could carry more data to the new activity so you can send other important information(like the position of the element for which to calculate stuff,  this depends of what kind of data and how you store it  ).

Comment: I understand how to start a new activity and i can do it from other activities. But my ListAdapter is of course an extra class, which looks like this: `public class modul_ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {...}`
The adapter class does not know `startActivity(i)`.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: @user1206662 Modify your `modul_listAdapter` constructor so you can also take a `Context` object and store it in a private variable, like `ctx`. Then in the activity where you create the adapter you pass the `Activity` context(whith the keyword `this`) in your adapter constructor. Then you ca use `ctx.startActivity(i)`. Also i see  you use the `LayoutInflater` so you already have somewhere(probably the constructor) a context reference(i don't know the code for you entire adapter class)

Comment: it works! i didn't really understand the meaning of `Context`, but now it's obvious! thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using xml for the button, add `android:onClick="onClick"` to it.

Comment: ok, thanks! but how does my main activity know in which listview row i clicked the button?

Answer (score 0):

Write a public method in your Activity like

```
public void onClick(View v) {
.....
}
```